# Override Conditional Formatting with Worksheet_SelectionChange

Tags: excel, vba, events, formatting

I have some code in a worksheet to highlight the row of a selected cell. However, this sheet has conditional formatting which colours some of the rows. The highlighting macro does not work on the rows where the formatting condition is being met (in the sense that the colour of the highlight is not overriding the colour of the conditional formatting).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

   Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone 
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 19 'Highlight row
End Sub
```

Does anyone know a way around this without removing the conditional formatting?
Eg. can I temporarily disable it for a selected row and re-enable it when the row is unselected?

The formatting is one rule applied to all cells. I figure in theory I could create an independent rule for every row (~500 of them) and then turn that off completely and later reapply it but that seems a little overboard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to use *ActiveCell* in your *Worksheet_SelectionChange* event macro. That is what **Target** is/does.

Modify your *Worksheet_SelectionChange* to be closer to the following.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Target.Name = "mySelection"
    Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    Target.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 19
End Sub
```

Now you will be constantly redefining a *named range* for each new selection of cells.

You didn't disclose what the CF rule actually was so I'm going to assume that is highlights cell that are not blank. Modify the existing CF rule to be of the *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* variety and adjust the following to suit your own CF rule then put it in the *Format values where this formula is true:* text box.

```
=AND(A1<>"", ROW(A1)<>ROW(mySelection))
```

By adding a boolean criteria within an AND function and constantly redefining the *mySelection* range to the current selection you can override the CF rule's formatting.

[image: Conditional Formatting Override]

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. I wasn't particularly hopeful of a solution to this, not mind one so tidy. When I select a conditionally formatted cell now and then select a different cell, the CF cell turns white until I select a third cell, at which point it will return back to its formatted colour. Is there a way around this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior (see [my sample here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100009401/Override_CF_rule.xlsb)) but I have run into similar situations with heavily formatted workbooks where a CF rule does not seem to immediately take effect. Consider posting a redacted copy of your workbook for direct examination.

Comment: @user2842721 - You might try removing the ColorIndex assignment from the *Worksheet_SelectionChange* and make the background color fill it's own CF rule based on `=ROW(A1)=ROW(mySelection)`. Leave the named range redefinition in the *Worksheet_SelectionChange* but let a new CF rule provide the row highlighting.

Comment: Problem was being caused by my formulas being set to manual. Guessing you may have been on automatic and thus not seeing same. Have added 'Calculate' to the end of my code and all is good now. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It's like a never ending problem, this! There is some other VBA code in the sheet that refreshes the data in the sheet with the CF. Effectively what it does is it clears the contents of the sheet, runs a SQL query and pastes the output back into the sheet. When nothing is updated in the SQL table the sheet looks the exact same post macro as before. For some reason, post running this macro, selecting a cell and with highlighting is taking 4-5 seconds (with a loading bar stating "updating cells" at the bottom).

Comment: Initially i had the problem where post macro the entire sheet was highlighted, but I corrected this with an if statement that turns the highlighting code off while the macro is running. What's really strange is that this sheet was already in a 'post macro' state when I added the highlighting code. I have tested the IF statement to make sure this is not causing the issue and it isn't. I was wondering if there's something obvious I'm missing or is this one where I'll have to trawl through the main macro?

Comment: If the 'main macro' was poorly written, it may involve code commands like `Range("A1").Select` which will throw your `Worksheet_SelectionChange` into conniptions. If you cannot rewrite the code to remove inefficient code like that, use `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the very beginning and `Application.EnableEvents = True` before the macro exits to ensure that everything gets turned back on. Consider [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel) for advise on improving the 'mainmacro'. Great site for improving inefficient (but working) code.

Comment: My code will definitely be inefficient. application.EnableEvents didn't seem to fix it but the problem does go away once I've saved the WB so as a temporary solution  ActiveWorkbook.Save at the end of the main macro is working.