# Override conditional formatting with Worksheet.BeforeDoubleClick event

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this rule to format every other row depending on criteria in column B:

```
=IF(ISEVEN(LEFT($B1, FIND("-", $B1)-1)),MOD(ROW(),2))
```

I also want to be able to double-click a cell in a particular column to toggle highlighting that row with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, tb.ListColumns("Domain").DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Name = "HighlightRow"
        With ActiveCell
            Range(Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Column), Cells(.Row, .CurrentRegion.Columns.Count + .CurrentRegion.Column - 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

1. With reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29870104/2319146), how can I override the rule so that the Worksheet.BeforeDoubleClick event takes precedence?
2. How can I adapt the Worksheet.BeforeDoubleClick event to toggle highlighting?

Comment: I believe you will need to clear the conditional formatting with your code from the cell. After the code runs, the conditional format rule will still be evaluated and format accordingly (TRUE/FALSE). To get around this, you will need to remove the format from the Target

Answer (score 1):

Before I start...I'm a little confused, is your conditional formatting formula supposed to be

```
=IF(ISEVEN(LEFT($B1, FIND("-", $B1)-1)),MOD(ROW(),2))
```

...which only formats Even numbers in column B on every Odd row?
leaving out all Odd numbers and all Even rows?

---

Anyway, you need to store the extra information of which cells are highlighted somewhere that the conditional formatting can use it.

### Easy Way...

The easiest suggestion would be to add a hidden column called `Highlight` and refer to it in the conditional format.

---

### Or Hard Way...

You could add a conditional format that takes priority and stops the others from being applied.  I still used the Named Range idea from the other solution.  I could have kept track of the highlighted range using a variable, but I think this works better.  I also made it so that you could have multiple colors if you wanted (but I didn't add prioritization).
 Enjoy...(I did)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Range("B:B"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        ToggleHighlight Target.EntireRow, Range("A2:H50")
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

### Toggle Highlight

```
Sub ToggleHighlight(Target As Range, _
           Optional TableArea As Range = Cells, _ 
           Optional Name As String = "Yellow", _
           Optional ColorIndex As Integer = 19)
Dim Formula As String
Dim HighlightedRows As Range
    ' Use unique names to allow multiple highlights/colors
    ' This is the formula we will apply to the highlighted area
    Formula = "=OR(TRUE,""Highlight""=""" & Name & """)"        

    On Error Resume Next
    ' Check if the target cell that was clicked is within the table area
    Set Target = Intersect(Target, TableArea)
    If Target is Nothing Then Exit
    ' Get the current highlighted rows
    Set HighlightedRows = ThisWorkbook.Names("HighlightedRows_" & Name).RefersToRange
    ThisWorkbook.Names("HighlightedRows_" & Name).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0

    If HighlightedRows Is Nothing Then
        Set HighlightedRows = Target    ' We'll apply .EntireRow later
    Else
        ' Remove previous Conditional Formats
        Dim Condition As FormatCondition
        For Each Condition In HighlightedRows.FormatConditions
            With Condition
                If .Formula1 = Formula Then .Delete
            End With
        Next
        ' Now, toggle the Target range/row
        If Intersect(HighlightedRows, Target) Is Nothing Then
            ' We know that both HighlightedRows and Target are Not Nothing, so
            Set HighlightedRows = Union(HighlightedRows, Target.EntireRow)
        Else
            ' We're going to limit the (Big) area to a single column, because it's slow otherwise
            Set HighlightedRows = InvertRange(Target.EntireRow, Intersect(HighlightedRows, TableArea.Columns(1)))
        End If
    End If
    ' Apply the new Conditional Formatting...
    If Not HighlightedRows Is Nothing Then
        ' HighlightedRows is still set to the EntireRow
        Set HighlightedRows = Intersect(HighlightedRows.EntireRow,TableArea)
        With HighlightedRows
            .Name = "HighlightedRows_" & Name
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:=Formula
            With .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count)
                ' Make sure it's first
                .SetFirstPriority
                ' and that no other format is applied
                .StopIfTrue = True
                .Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndex
            End With
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

### Invert Range

```
Function InvertRange(Target As Excel.Range, Optional LargeArea As Variant) As Excel.Range
' Returns the Inverse or Relative Complement of Target in LargeArea
' InvertRange = LargeArea - Target
Dim BigArea As Excel.Range
Dim Area As Excel.Range
Dim Cell As Excel.Range

    If IsMissing(LargeArea) Then
        Set BigArea = Target.Parent.UsedRange
    Else
        Set BigArea = LargeArea
    End If

    If Target Is Nothing Then
        Set InvertRange = BigArea
    ElseIf BigArea Is Nothing Then
        ' nothing to do; will return Nothing
    Else
        For Each Area In BigArea.Areas
            For Each Cell In Area.Cells
                If Intersect(Cell, Target) Is Nothing Then
                    If InvertRange Is Nothing Then
                        Set InvertRange = Cell
                    Else
                        Set InvertRange = Union(InvertRange, Cell)
                    End If
                End If
            Next Cell
        Next Area
    End If
End Function
```

### Edit

I updated it to include TableArea, to limit the Highlights, as well as a Check that the Target and Table Area are on the same sheet and intersect.

Comment: Thank you; this is more than I anticipated. [1] The CF formula is correct, if a little counter-intuitive; I assume I do not need to change it. [2] If I highlight a second row I get a type mismatch error. [3] I was hoping to limit the highlighting to the table, and toggle it by double-clicking the Domain column.

Comment: @user2319146, [1] Yes, we are changing the range that the formula applies to, instead of using the formula to determine the conditions.  The second half of the CF formula is only to help me find it, so I can delete it, it doesn't change the outcome. [2] Where, on what line? [3] You can easily limit the columns, just use `Set HighlightedRows = Intersect(HighlightedRows.EntireRow, Columns("A:H"))` before the `With HighlightedRows` line